# access denied in python

Tags: python

hi everybody
i wanna take a dir from one directory and os doesn't allow me to do this work(for example /etc/openvpn in linux) and i know i should be root but i don't know how can i do this with python.

Answer (score 1):

you have to start the process as root.  You can run "sudo yourscript.py" as your normal user account or log in as root or run "su -" to become root and then run your script.

Your script cannot obtain root privileges after it starts running.  That's just not how unix/linux systems work.

Comment: Or `gksudo` for a graphical password prompt.

Comment: i think you don't understand my question.i know i should be root but how can i root in python,which module should i use or anything else,

Comment: If you are root when you start your program, then your program runs as root.  You don't use any module.

Answer (score 0):

You will get Access to the path 'C:\tmp' is denied, if you call open on an existing directory instead of a file.

Example:

```
f = open('C:/tmp', 'w')
```

Should be:

```
f = open('C:/tmp/temp.txt', 'w')
```